# How to stop metal bar from rotating?

Tags: installation

I made a DIY pull up bar by putting a barbell onto a barbell holder, however it rotates a bit when hanging on.

How can I stop it from rotating given this set up?

(*There's only 1 barbell in my set up*)

[image]

Comment: I was thinking of putting industrial strength velcro on the corner of the holders

Answer (score 2):

The bar is rotating because there is little friction between the bar and your supports.  Glue some soft rubber strips on the supports where the bar sits and you'll be all set.

On a side note, one limitation a *lot* of people have in strength training is in their grip strength.  This is manifest by the ubiquitous use of lifting straps.  If your grip is strong you won't need to prevent the bar from rolling.  That said, to each his own.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid drilling the bar as this could weaken it if it were used as a lifting bar. I would clamp a pair of vise-grips (locking pliers)on to the bar. Place the pliers on area an not likely to be used when weight lifting as the pliers may gouge the bar. The pliers will only rotate until they hit the wall. If need be you could pad the pliers to prevent marking the wall.

Comment: great minds think alike. Might need some duct tape around the bar to prevent slipping... Also add a thin strip of duct tape or thin coat of hot glue to the bracket saddle to keep slipping and vibration down.

Answer (score 0):

Stop by your local kitchen supply store (or any big-box store that sells kitchen goods) and pick up a pair of rubber "grippers" intended to help you open a pickle jar. Put one in each support, then place the bar on top of that.

Answer (score -1):

You need a clamp fitted to one or both of the supports.

Sometimes just drilling, tapping and using a bolt will be sufficient, but if you want to avoid damage from the bar rotating then perhaps a friction pad clamp would be better. Think of a G clamp...

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what side your hanging from wrap electrical wire around the bar in the opposite direction a few times and a fix the wire end to the bar with a knot.